# Transferred Laravel app to new server - not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I created my first Laravel (3.2) app awhile back on a VPS that I had. Now, the time has come for me to move to a dedicated server, and I need to move that app to the new server.

I used RSYNC via SSH and transferred everything over to the new server, but when I pull up the webpage in my browswer (public folder), I see a blank page.

I can pull up a file in my public folder, but not the app.

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I guess that it could have been a number of things, but I looked into my error logs (Ubuntu)

```
/var/log/apache2/error.log
```

and saw this error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'yield' (T_YIELD), expecting '(' in /var/www/path/to/laravel/helpers.php on line 563
```

so I did a Google search.

There is a Laravel function called yield() that collides with a reserved name in PHP 5.5 that was not in PHP 5.4. It so happens that my old server had PHP 5.4.

Found [this](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/3298407238fd3e212cdf8d829adc6f519b941052) which helped me to find all instances of 'yield()' in Laravel and change to '_yield()'. Problem solved!

Comment: I upgraded to PHP 5.5 and this answer helped me.

Comment: This fixed my upgrade to PHP 5.6 aswell, Thanks.